# how to tell youtube that my website is the traffic source of the embeded video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

If users embed their Youtube videos in my website, they need to know the effect of my website in their Youtube analytics. So, how should I alter this line:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/X8yqwvYo5PA?html5=1" id="videoiframe"></iframe>
```

to tell Youtube that this video is embedded in my website while being played to let it recognize my website as its referrer.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing specific that we recommend doing to get that to register. Are you sure playbacks aren't being properly attributed as coming from an embed on your domain when the owner of the video looks at their YouTube Analytics report?

It is possible to set an `origin=` parameter when constructing your embed code (see https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player) but that is for the purposes of protecting against third-party code hijacking control of your player via the API, not for Analytics attribution.